# $V'(\mathbf{x}) f(\mathbf{x}) \leq 0$ implies $V(\mathbf{x}(t)) \leq V(\mathbf{x}(0))$ for all $t \geq 0$

Tags: nonlinear-system, lyapunov-functions

Consider a nonlinear dynamical system
\begin{equation}
\dot{\mathbf{x}}(t) = f(\mathbf{x}(t)), \quad \mathbf{x}(0) = \mathbf{x}_0, \quad t \geq 0
\end{equation}
and Lyapunov function $V: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Since
\begin{equation}
V'(\mathbf{x}) f(\mathbf{x}) \leq 0, \quad \forall~\mathbf{x} \in D,
\end{equation}
show $\forall~\mathbf{x}(0) \in D$, $V(\mathbf{x}(t)) \leq V(\mathbf{x}(0))$ for all $t \geq 0$.

This statement holds true to me intuitively, but I think this statement requires some rigorous justification.

Given $V'(\mathbf{x})f(\mathbf{x}) \leq 0$ for all $\mathbf{x} \in D$, then we know that $\dot{V} (\mathbf{x}(0)) = V'(\mathbf{x}(0)) f(\mathbf{x}(0)) \leq 0$ for $\mathbf{x}_0 \in D$. However, to show the statement, I need $\forall~t > 0$, $\dot{V}(\mathbf{x}(t)) \leq 0$. Just knowing $\dot{V} (\mathbf{x}(0)) \leq 0$ is not enough, I think. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Given $V(x(t))$, you have $$\frac{d}{dt} V(x(t)) = V'(x) \dot{x} = V'(x) f(x) \le 0$$ i.e $V$ is non-increasing in time and hence $V(x(t)) \le V(x(0))$.

Comment: What is $D$ here? The claim is clearly true as long as $\mathbf{x}(t)$ stays in the region $D$, but if it may leave $D$ there is no reason for the claim to hold for all $t>0$.